# Wix/JS/Corvid: Passing a string to a file

Tags: javascript, velo

Does anyone have any insight on how I can pass a string to a file so the browser opens the default calendar application?

I have a library that generates iCalendar information, I take the instance and toString it, then I need that passed to a .ical file.

There does not seem to be a Corvid based solution.